# How to run pkg.go.dev locally as a godoc replacement?

Tags: go, godoc, go-get

`godoc` has been removed from the go standard install [since 1.12](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25443) and looks like it wont be updated anytime soon. `pkg.go.dev` at least [appears to be its successor](https://github.com/golang/pkgsite). It also has additional documentation features like grabbing the `README.md` file and rendering it in the documentation page.

For these reasons I was hoping to switch over to using `pkg.go.dev` locally to view and create documentation for small internal packages. The major issue is that unlike `godoc` there does not seem to be a clear usage guide. I also do not know if `pkpg.go.dev` is completely overkill for this task. So I would like to know:

1. Can and should `pkg.go.dev` be used as a local `godoc` replacement?
2. If yes, how would I run it for this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run pkgsite locally.

`go install golang.org/x/pkgsite/cmd/pkgsite@latest && pkgsite`

References:

1. https://tip.golang.org/doc/comment
2. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/pkgsite/cmd/pkgsite

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [x/tools/godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc) that has the previous godoc tool

Answer (score 0):

Running `godoc` [1] on its own worked for me, but was really slow because it generates docs for every single package in the standard library, while I only care about the local package that I am working on. To that end, if your package is in a folder called `something`, you can move the folder so that it looks like this:

```
godoc/src/something
```

Then, go to the `godoc` folder, and run

```
godoc -goroot .
```

Then, browse to `localhost:6060`. Alternatively, another site is available for
Go docs [2].

1. https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/cmd/godoc
2. https://godocs.io

Comment: Unfortunately, while godoc starting with Go 1.19 automatically picks up the new go document comment features of lists and links, the links are broken because somehow the "generic" go document comment parser assumes a certain URL structure when it generates links. Yuk, it looks as if there is no proper full AST inbetween, but rather some assumptions already in the comment parser.